# Move product attributes after summary on single product page

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, debug

I must say i don't know coding or programming. I did copy paste this code, inside my functions and it is working perfect. The code shows all the woocommerce product attributes after the product description summary.

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'show_attributes', 25 );
function show_attributes() {
  global $product;
  $product->list_attributes(); 
}
```

But inside the debug_log this lines are appearing:

```
PHP Notice:  WC_Product::list_attributes is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wc_display_product_attributes instead. in /home/public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3837
```

So i tried changing this line:

**$product->list_attributes();**

to this

**$product->wc_display_product_attributes();**

But it didn't work. It breaks all my frontpage with multiple lines of code errors.

So i am here for help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list_attributes` is a method of `WC_Product` class called with `->` operator and the `wc_display_product_attributes` is a simple function.

This will fix the issue:

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'show_attributes', 25 );
function show_attributes() {
  global $product;
  wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
}
```